# App.crashes after receiving a Push Notification on Capacitor 4

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

Hello i am having problem with my Capacitor 4 project. I am trying to use Push Notifications with FCM and whenever i try to do that, the app on Android devices crashes, even when i trying to send from Firebase using the token of the device. For iOS version works just fine.

service.ts

```
async registerFCM() {

  await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification received: ', notification);
  });

  await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification action performed', notification.actionId, notification.inputValue);
  });
  

  PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async result => {
    if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android') {
            await PushNotifications.register()
            PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async ({ value }) => {
                console.log(value);
                this.submitFCM(value); //This one i use for Android
            });
          }
          else{
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        await PushNotifications.register();

        // Get FCM token instead the APN one returned by Capacitor
        FCM.getToken()
            .then((r) => {
                console.log(`Token: ${r.token}`)

                this.submitFCM(r.token);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
    } else {
        // Show some error
    }
  });

  let device: any = await Device.getInfo();
  let id = await Device.getId(); 
  device.uuid = id.uuid;

  this.device = device;
 }



async submitFCM(token) {
    console.log('token', token);
    let url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'registerFCM'; 
    let data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        api_signature: this.api_signature,
        registrationId: token,
        app_version: this.appData.APP_VERSION,

        device: {
            platform: this.device.platform,
            uuid: this.device.uuid,
            cordova: this.device.cordova,
            model: this.device.model,
            manufacturer: this.device.manufacturer,
            version: this.device.version,
        }
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options })
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Push has been registered', data);
    })
}
```

PHP function

```
function registerFCM()
{
//print_r('goes into fcm');
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$data = $_POST;
$response['success'] = true; // 1
//print_r($data);
$userDetails = getUserBySignature();
$uid = $userDetails->uid;

$fcm = array(
    'id_user' => $uid,
    'register_id' =>  $data['registrationId'],
    'platform' => $data['device']['platform'],
    'version' => $data['device']['version'],
    'uuid' => $data['device']['uuid'],
    'model' => $data['device']['model'],
    'manufacturer' => $data['device']['manufacturer'],
    'app_version' => $data['app_version'],
    'added_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  );

  $db = getDB();

   $sql = "INSERT INTO fcm(id_user, register_id, platform, version, uuid, model, manufacturer, app_version, added_at) ";
   $sql .= "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($fcm));

   $push['message'] = 'Hello'; 
   //$devices = $data['registrationId']['token'];
   $devices = $data['registrationId'];
   pushNotification($push, $devices);

   echo json_encode($response);

 }
```

I know that there is no error in PHP because it used to work in my cordova version

Any help?

I tried to use Push Notifications and the app is crashing on Android devices

UPDATE: ERROR I AM GETTING IN ANDROID STUDIO

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myproject.mobile, PID: 15559
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.myproject.mobile.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myproject.mobile.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myproject.mobile-pp5so-jVTphVOgyLGriOfA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myproject.mobile-pp5so-jVTphVOgyLGriOfA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3950)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1879)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:944)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rovespier.mobile.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rovespier.mobile-pp5so-jVTphVOgyLGriOfA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rovespier.mobile-pp5so-jVTphVOgyLGriOfA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3945)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1879) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:944)
```

MainActivity file

```
package com.myproject.mobile;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.codetrixstudio.capacitor.GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth;
import com.epicshaggy.filepicker.FilePicker;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Initializes the Bridge
        this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
        // Additional plugins you've installed go here
        add(com.getcapacitor.community.facebooklogin.FacebookLogin.class);
        add(com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin.class);
        add(GoogleAuth.class);
        add(FilePicker.class);
      }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message from Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry i updated to show the Error i am getting

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by changing this

```
  <service
        android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

to this

```
 <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is the answer to this question. Now i am getting notifications but the device token is changing each time i install the app. Plus i am not getting  information message to Allow Notifications or not. Any help?

Comment: it doesn't look like you use checkPermissions anywhere

Comment: Yes i don't use anywhere except from camera because i think it goes with the plugin.  You mean in AndroidManifest.xml like this one? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> How do i use it for Notifications and uploading Video and Audio files?

Comment: Plus, this one should get Permissions right?  PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(async result => {
        if (result.receive === 'granted') {